# Reported Speech for thinking about past

Tags: reported-speech

We use would have past participal for hypothetical/imagination sentences. Do we need to use them in a reported speech?

Direct:(Talking to myself) Probably this would be the last time I am here.

Indirect:(Telling someone) I knew that would have been the last time I was there.

Comment: Yes, you backshift when you're thinking about the past. But your first sentence really should be: *Probably this will be the last time I am here*. So the indirect sentence is:  *I knew that would be the last time I was there.*

Comment: Why not 'would' ? If I don't say 'probably' then the sentence Direct: 'this would be the last time I am here'. Indirect: 'I knew that would have been the last time I was there'. I'm using ' would' for assumption. Now what would you say?. Is the indirect correct now?.

Comment: In the first sentence, I would instead say *probably this **will** be the last time I am here.*

Comment: So you mean we can't change 'would be' in the reporting speech?

Comment: It depends on the meaning of *would be*.